# How was the highlighted value obtained?

Tags: current, transformer, impedance

[image]

I'm currently calculating the excitation current for a transformer but I keep getting the wrong answer. I tried converting the highlighted values to rectangular form (first highlighted value) but still couldn't obtain the same answer as the one given below (second highlighted value). I am trying to achieve the value '2.678∠-86.8'.

Comment: There are two highlighted sections. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to get the second highlighted value (2.678∠-86.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm trying to get the second highlighted value (2.678∠-86.8)*

Well, before that you have \$\dfrac{53.6\angle 3.2}{j20}\$ and that is the same as: -

$$\dfrac{53.6\angle 3.2}{20\angle90}$$

And that equals: -

$$\dfrac{53.6}{20}\angle(3.2-90) = 2.68\angle -86.8$$

Comment: I see, so the j value is always 90 degrees in this context?

Comment: @miu.spiro yes it is exactly the same as "i" in mathematics (the complex operator).